# CSS messing up eBay listing?

Tags: html, css, ebay-design-templates

I'm using my jobs HTML template made with 3rd party software, and trying to add it to an eBay listing, but the listing is displaying improperly.

I am getting a visual error when I try to add this to an eBay listing. In Chrome, this happens: https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/cropped%20ebay.png?_subject_uid=155856861&w=AAAV20ym1M3Czc9VF2DUwBU2omimJFfQErKaYnrwOdyCyg

In other browsers, this happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iicy8.png

Trying to track down this issue, it seems to be somewhat related to the CSS. If I remove the line ".xr_ap {position: absolute; border:none;}" from the CSS file, it renders on the page somewhat-properly, but the images are missing.

I'm not sure how to fix this? Why would using Absolute in CSS cause this issue?

If anyone could help, or needs more info, please let me know.

(Edit: I can only include 2 images per post. I am going to have to reply to this with the other links...)

Comment: Here is an example of the HTML version of the page: http://spyridon.site.nfoservers.com/XaraTest/

Here is CSS being used: http://spyridon.site.nfoservers.com/XaraTest/index_htm_files/xr_main.css

Comment: Without seeing the eBay's DOM I can't say for sure, but my guess is that your content is added to an iFrame.  Have you tried `position: relative` or copying the elements from the malformed page to a fiddle to play around with it?

Comment: Would changing the html and css to inline css fix the problem? See with jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k1y44qvh/

Comment: @adamdc78 - I tried relative instead of absolute and it still has the problem. I'm not sure what you mean by copying to a fiddle though, unless if you mean the link Andrew sent? But I'm not sure how to use it really.

Comment: @AndrewH - I tried the code from there and it still seems to have the same issue.

Comment: Here is a live listing that is using the HTML. Scroll down and you will see what I mean with the error - http://www.ebay.com/itm/270884320336?item=270884320336&viewitem=&vxp=mtr - if you right click the frame it is creating, you can view the source that will show the HTML of the listing. And I posted the CSS above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your #xr_xr to:

```
 <div id="xr_xr" style="width: 955px; height: 2045px; left: 50%; margin-left: -478px; border: none; position: relative; display: block">
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2aqLuh8v/).  Not all of the CSS is there, so the tabs don't look right, but your content does (tested by editing the DOM directly from Chrome on the eBay page too).

Having set your position to absolute and your top to 0, it was rendering at the top of the containing element.

**EDIT**

Additionally, you've got `top` set without `left` on your text spans; you will want to add a left value to the css for `xr_tl`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is "mostly" working now. My only issue now is the alignment of the logo and images seems to be improper on some browsers. Please check this listing: http://www.ebay.com/itm/270884320336?item=270884320336&viewitem=&vxp=mtr - on Chrome its rendering nearly perfect, but on firefox is a little off. Any idea on the issue here? Thanks again!

Comment: Doing a little more research, it seems like the text itself is aligning itself more and more to the right with each line? Since it's absolute why is it doing this?

Comment: If you inspect element on the lines, you'll see that the 'top' value is applied as a margin; you'll want to add `left: 10px` or something similar to the CSS for `xr_tl`.